# ¿Como se baja un proyecto de git hub desde una version anterior a la ultima?

Tags: github

Como se puede bajar de GitHub una version anterior del proyecto? Asumiendo que es una versión que no tiene un tag asociado, por ejemplo, en algún punto de la historia de la semana pasada.

Comment: quieres clonar desde ese commit en particular, en un directorio limpio? Por qué no te sirve descargar el estado actual del proyecto y luego usar checkout para retroceder localmente?

Comment: si, hacer el checkout  después de clonar el proyecto me sirve, muchas gracias

Comment: Entonces las soluciones que te dieron están impecables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes clonar el repositorio y luego ejecutar

```
git checkout <hash commit>
```

así iras al commit que deseas, luego puedes crear una rama basada en ese commit por ejemplo

```
git checkout -b <nombre-rama>
```

o también luego de clonarlo puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
git reset --hard <hash commit>
```

[git-reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacerlo desde Github de esta manera:

1. Abres el repositorio desde la web de Github.
2. Haces clic en los **commits** del repositorio. Te aparece una lista ordenada cronológicamente.
3. Buscas el commit que te interesa (por ejemplo, el de la semana pasada). A la derecha de la fila del commit está el botón "Browse the repository at this point in the history". Haces clic en él.
4. Se despliega una lista de archivos. El botón de la derecha "Clone or download" te permite descargar los archivos de este commit en particular.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres bajar una versión de un repositorio de Git, basta bajar el proyecto completo. Si está bajo el control de versiones de Git, quiere decir que puedes ir a cualquier parte de la historia.

Para ir a un commit especifico en un repositorio de git usas:

```
git checkout <sha1>
```

donde `sha1` es el hash del commit en ambos formatos (corto y largo), un ejemplo sería:

```
git checkout 97dd2ae065771908ee9ae0fa08ccdb58b5a6b18f
```

La documentación oficial es [Git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem--detachltcommitgt)

También puedes ver otros comandos en este excelente [Cheat Sheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html)